# Returning with 'if' statement vs logical OR in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Function `fnc()` returns either a DOM element or null.  This is called from within another function where when null is returned there is nothing more to do.

As null will always evaluate as false and an object as true the following will work:

```
var parentResult = fnc( arg ) || return false;
var childResult = fnc( parentResult.id ) || return false;
```

But I never see this sort of syntax used in Javascript, instead it always seems to be written as (give or take formatting, `var` keywords, and an explicit `=== null` in the condition):

```
var parentResult = fnc( arg );
if( !parentResult ) { return false };
var childResult = fnc( parentResult.id );
if( !childResult ) { return false };
```

To me the former is tidier and more readable as a result, yet there must be a reason it is not used.

So given the return value of `fnc()` can be relied upon, is there a good reason not to use logical ORs to terminate the function rather than separate `if` statements?

Comment: For me the if would be more readable in this example. A beginner (I don't know if this code will be viewed by beginners/starters) wouldn't understand this kind of code.

Comment: I feel like this is just an opinionated thread, but what JavaScript have you read? If you look at the source code of some libraries, it's all over the place.

Comment: An even more "clever" way would be:
`parentResult = fnc( arg ) && childResult = fnc( parentResult.id ) || return false;`

But generally this style is frowned upon.

Comment: @g.kertesz the first thing to frown upon it would be the JavaScript parser, since it's a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, fuyushimoya and sheliak, I have edited to correct the logical error.

Comment: Apologies for the dumb in hindsight question, I suppose the alternative 'tidy' approach is to do the assignment within the `if` condition, although in that case I accept it is less readable, and more prone to error, because of the confusion with comparison operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see the first example used anywhere because it is invalid JavaScript. `return` is a **statement**, it cannot be part of an **expression** (`||`).

Comment: The question has a mistake, but this doesn't answer the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: @Goose: how does that not answer the question? It's not used because it is invalid. Why else do you think is it not used?

Comment: I believe his question is more about if vs ||, rather than return in particular.

Comment: The title of the question says otherwise.

Comment: It does answer the question, and once allowed I will accept it.  I have no idea how I came to believe that would work as I have tested it before and so only asked ahead of rewriting some code.  Obviously the reason it is not used is because it does not work though, so that is clearly an answer.  Thanks Goose.

Comment: My mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid, you can't have "return" within an assignment:

```
var parentResult = fnc( arg ) || return false;
```

But this is valid, and a common idiom:

```
var parentResult = fnc( arg ) || false;
```

You could also do this:

```
var parentResult = !!fnc( arg );
```

The double-bang converts the value to a Boolean -- it's sort of a trick, so some will say it's a bad idea.

There are lots of choices.

Comment: `var parentResult = !!fnc(arg)` doesn't do the same thing as `var parentResult = fnc(arg) || false`.  In the first case, `parentResult` with either be `true` or `false`.  In the second, `parentResult` will be an *object* or `false`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I wanted to demonstrate a similar pattern but forgot that in this case a real value should be assigned if false is not.

Answer (score 0):

For most people, the more the source code follows natural language, the more it is readable / understandable.
The lengthy notation is more like natural language: "execute the function, then if the result is null, stop".

Answer (score 0):

I would say the logical OR is used fairly often, and for short hand, I prefer it over a one line if statement if possible. There are many reasons someone might choose to use an if statement instead.

- **Readability**. It is closer to natural language.
- **Expandable**. If the conditional, or the resulting action needs to be expanded, and if statement will need to be used anyways.
- **Consistency**. Perhaps the code around it is using if statements, and a logical OR would just look out of place.
- **Ignorance**. I didn't know about the logical OR until probably 6 months into coding.

It's definitely a personal choice, as long as they both give the same result.